# Excel Formula: Not recognising two cells as equal

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

In my Excel Spreadsheet, I have the following formula (in column Q):

```
=IF(AND(I2=P2,I2<>""),"FUNC_FROM",(IF(AND(J2=P2,J2<>""),"PHYS_FROM",(IF(P2="","","NEW_FROM")))))
```

This is comparing whats's in column P to column I & J. My intented results are:

> - If P=I AND I is not null, Q should show FUNC_FROM;
> - If P=J AND J is not null, Q should show PHYS_FROM;
> - If P is null, Q should be null
> - Else Q should show NEW_FROM

My issue is that only the last two bullets seem to be working, my Q column is either populated with NEW_FROM if P is not null, or is left null if P is null. When the value should be PHYS_FROM or FUNC_FROM, I am getting a value of NEW_FROM instead.

After looking into the issue, I have determined that Excel is simply not recognizing the cells as equal when they are so, hence I am getting these results from my formula.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

**Note:** If I manually type in the value into P, then it will recognize cells as equal if they are so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that a blank-looking cell is not necessarily a blank cell, and that the cells `xyzzy<space>` and `xyzzy` may *look* the same to you but Excel knows better.

*Check* the actual contents of the cells, you may have to start using something like `trim()` to remove leading and trailing spaces before comparison.

For example, here's a sample where the `I2` cell has a space on the end and that causes the first test to be false:

[image]

Editing the `I2` cell to *remove* that space at the end solves the problem:

[image]

Comment: Yeah that was it. I thought I checked this first, but in my sleep-deprived state I must've assumed I did it already. Cheers